# How to treat apostrophe ' as a part of a string, instead of a string end, in where clause in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to filter down to certain variables in the WHERE clause, but am running into issues with the variables containing apostrophes, and therefore snowflake is cutting up the strings.

This is what I was hoping would work: `WHERE holiday IN ('Valentine's Day', 'Chris's Birthday')`

I have also tried double apostrophes: `WHERE holiday IN ('Valentine''s Day', 'Chris''s Birthday')`

as well as quotation marks: `WHERE holiday IN ("Valentine's Day", "Chris's Birthday")`

and backslashes: `WHERE holiday IN ('Valentine\'s Day\', 'Chris\'s Birthday\')`

Comment: Usually double apostrophes should work. How is your table data looking? Please provide a minimal example and the corresponding complete query.

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape the last quote - it is the end of the string. So,
not this `IN ('Valentine\'s Day\', 'Chris\'s Birthday\')` but instead: `IN ('Valentine\'s Day', 'Chris\'s Birthday')`

For further reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text#escape-sequences-in-single-quoted-string-constants

Answer (score 0):

Or use double $$

```
where holiday in ($$Valentine's Day$$, $$Chris's Birthday$$)
```